# Nested resources Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, restful, rails4

criei dois models na aplicação Rails, e fiz o relacionamento deles através da declaração nas classes e no banco também.
Adicionei a configuração para ativar o nested resources no arquivo routes, as rotas foram criadas porém não trabalham da forma como deveriam, vou colocar o exemplo abaixo:

```
Model Project
has_many :steps

Model Steps
belongs_to :project

resources :projects  do
    resources :steps
end
```

Porém, quando eu bato a url /projects/1/steps ele sempre cai na ação index do controller Steps, que retorna um Steps.all.

A forma correta de fazer isso, é só reescrevendo a ação index mesmo??

Comment: Rapaz, ficou confuso... você definiu a action `index` do Steps? Ou tá perguntando se tem que definir...

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é exatamente o que deveria.
Com o comando `rake routes` é possível ver o seguinte resultado:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                    Controller#Action
project_steps GET    /projects/:project_id/steps(.:format)          steps#index
```

Ou seja, sua URL `/projects/:project_id/steps` está apontando para a controller `steps`e a action `index`.

Caso você queira direcionar para outra ação específica que não a index, você pode criar uma rota para ela como:

```
resources :projects  do
  resources :steps do
    get :minha_acao, on: :collection
  end
end
```

Que irá responder a:

```
/projects/:project_id/steps/minha_acao
```

Se você trocar `collection` por `member` a URL será:

```
/projects/:project_id/steps/:step_id/minha_acao
```

Note também que o verbo criado foi o GET, mas poderia também ser POST, PUT ou DELETE, dependendo da sua necessidade.